# Android GLES blocks UI update

Tags: android, user-interface, opengl-es-2.0

DI have a GLES20 glsurfaceview that sends an fps status string to my main activity via a messageHandler which I want to display on the screen while the GL is running.

```
public static Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        String message = (String)msg.obj;
        Globals.stats.setText(message);
        Globals.stats.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Globals.stats.invalidate();
    }
};
```

Global.stats points to an onscreen textview.

During the time the GLES code is running and updating the screen the textview does not display.  Once the GL rendering stops the textview does update with the last sent message and appears.

Is there anyway I can tell OpenGL or the surfaceview to yield and allow all the UI elements to update before continuing?

The layout is a relative layout with the textview on it, ie

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:gravity="fill">
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
         android:text="Medium Text"
         android:id="@+id/statsTextView"
         android:textColor="#ffffffff"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:background="#80000000" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

The GLES code is taken from many examples on the web.  A glsurf class

```
public class GLSurf extends GLSurfaceView {

private final GLRenderer mRenderer;

public GLSurf(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mRenderer = new GLRenderer(context);
    setRenderer(mRenderer);

    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    mRenderer.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    mRenderer.onResume();
}

}
```

And a public class

```
GLRenderer implements Renderer {
```

class that uses the

```
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
```

to draw the GLES output and then uses

```
MainActivity.messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

to send the fps status.

Is there any better way to get the textview to update while the GLES is running?  The message does get sent and received because once the GL stops the textview is updated with the latest frame number and fps info.

Comment: There is no way to tell them to yield, because there is no need to. They run independently. GLSurfaceView has a dedicated renderer thread, View elements are drawn by the main UI thread, and they are not mutually exclusive unless your app chooses to make them so.

Comment: I added some more info to hopefully help work out why or fix it?